# Do I need to pull up the I2C voltage to the VCC of a ADC?

Tags: adc, i2c

I am planning to use LTC2451 which is a ADC with I2C interface.  The main bus voltage that supplies the LTC2451 & the MCU is 3.7V and the GPIO voltage of the MCU is 1.8V.  Is it safe to pull up the SDA & SCL lines of the ADC to 1.8V when the ADC VCC is 3.7V?

Comment: Are you sure that 1.8v registers as a "high" for the I2C?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Datasheet says you must pull to Vcc. Look at the Vil and Vih.

[image]

Comment: Oh yes.  I missed this.  Thank you!

Comment: I'm not sure what you're referring to when writing *"it must"*. But pulling up to 1.8V will not work, as shown in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it safe to pull up the SDA & SCL lines of the ADC to 1.8V when the ADC VCC is 3.7V?

Assuming you use pull-up resistors in the range of kΩ, the chance of a fire hazard or electrical shock is very small.
**EDIT** However, when data from this device in this configuration is used in a safety application, it could form a safety hazard, because the I<sup>2</sup>C is driven in undefined states as elaborated below.

**Will it work?**

**No**, it will not.
According the datasheet V<sub>IH</sub> must be at least 0.7 * V<sub>CC</sub>.

[image]

> The -main bus voltage that supplies the LTC2451 & the MCU is 3.7V

So, in your case Vcc = 3.7 V. And therefore, V<sub>IH</sub> > 0.7 * 3.7V = 2.6 V.
Pulling the lines up to 1.8V will not achieve that.

You should check whether the MCU allows for voltages higher than 1.8V on the I<sup>2</sup>C bus, otherwise you'll need a level shifter.

If you read the datasheet further (page 7), **from the point of view of the LTC2451** only the SDA requires a pull-up to V<sub>CC</sub> (because the device can only be in slave mode).

[image]

Comment: You probably want to be careful saying that it is safe to bias the inputs of a CMOS chip to a level between the the defined Voltage Input Low (max) and the Voltage Input  High (min). It is never good to do this because it puts the device into an undefined state and who knows what could happen to the chip. My advice is to replace the first part of your answer with something that reflects the invalid nature of operating a digital device with its inputs biased in the no mans land between the valid digital logic levels.

Comment: @MichaelKaras The first part of my answer addresses the use of the word safe. The second part addresses the functionality: it will not (quite likely) work. Or did you mean using a device in undefined states also leads to a safety hazard?

Comment: I am saying it may very well not be safe for the ADC chip. Invalid conditions for one chip could feasibly cascade to other devices on the board. By your even putting the first part of your answer makes it look like you are saying it is OK to bias an input in the invalid logic level range. The professional thing to do is to either delete that part or revise it like I suggested. Keep in mind that many question posters here are not engineers and need to be guided to the correct ways to do things. Sometimes the literal answer is best left unwritten.

Comment: @MichaelKaras I'll add the part that using a device in its undefined states will cause undefined behavior and may cause a safety hazard when data used from the device is used in a safety application. Meanwhile, could you please motivate why it would not be safe for the ADC chip itself?

Comment: I cannot speak for the specific design of the ADC chip because I did not design it nor have I ever even used it. With CMOS logic there are PMOS and NMOS transistors stacked between the voltage rails with their gates tied to the input. The defined input voltage levels are specified so that just one of the transistors is on at a time. When an invalid logic level is applied to the gates of these transistors both transistors will be partially on at the same time. This dramatically increases the current that flows through the stack from VDD to GND. (continued)

Comment: (continued from above) This condition will also cause the internal output of that logic stage to most likely also be at an invalid level and can cascade deeper into the chip. The increased current flowing can cause the silicon area to heat beyond its design limits and age the junctions or even lead to catastrophic failure on the worst case.

Comment: @MichaelKaras The SCL and/or SDA dwells at voltage level between the defined states **every transient**!! Then this shoot through you're talking will happen all the time during I2C communication.

Comment: Yes indeed but the chip design is done to allow for transition on the CMOS inputs. There is a good reason that the data sheet for most parts specifies a maximum time for the rise and fall time between valid logic levels.  Biasing an input to a CMOS device to an invalid logic level is not a valid logic level transition and if done could conceivably be left in the condition for a long time.

Comment: "Safe" doesn't have as restrictive of a definition as you seem to think. "Is it safe to do X?" is a normal way to ask if X will work.

Comment: @Justin English is not my native language. I'll keep it in mind, but I think it doesn't harm the answer to take it literally.